# Playframework: how can I initialize an input box in a form?

Tags: forms, scala, datetime, playframework

Inside a web form I have input boxes like these:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="dt" name="dt" value=@form("dt")><br />
<input type="text" id="f0" name="f0" size="12" list=lst>
```

I am mapping the fields to a class:

```
case class Data(dt: Date, f0: String...)
```

When I submit the form I am able to fetch the values inserted in the boxes. However, I wanted to initialize the first input box with the current date. I tried, like it was documented, by returning the following from the main action:

```
Ok(views.html.index(form.fill(new Data(new Date(), ""))))
```

But it did not work out.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: You could try to change the input type to `"text"` to see if it fill the field correctly, maybe it's a problem with the format of the date

Comment: I can confirm it's a problem with the date format. The default date format is `yyyy-MM-dd` which is not compatible with a `datetime-local` input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First define a custom `Formatter` that has the date pattern needed by the [datetime-local input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) using Java's [date format pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

```
import play.api.data.format._

val dateTimeLocal: Formatter[Date] = Formats.dateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm")
```

Then define to/from a `Form` using `mapping` and `of`.

```
val dataForm = Form(
  mapping(
    "dt" -> of(dateTimeLocal),
    "f0" -> text
  )(Data.apply)(Data.unapply)
)
```

Now you can use a form helper to display an `<input type="datetime-local">`:

```
@helper.inputText(dataForm("dt"), 'type -> "datetime-local")
```

This produces the following HTML snippet, with the correct input `type` and date pattern:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="dt" name="dt" value="2017-11-16T08:19" />
```

You'll get a date/time picker when you view this in Chrome, but not currently in browsers like Firefox (as of November 2017). You may wish to consider [this note](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local) on MDN:

> Because of the limited browser support for `datetime-local`, and the variations in how the inputs work, it may currently still be best to use a framework or library to present these, or to use a custom input of your own. Another option is to use separate `date` and `time` inputs, each of which is more widely supported than `datetime-local`.

Comment: It seems to work properly now, except the AM/PM part in the datetime-local input type is not initialized. Additionally, when the page is generated I see this in the html: 
`<input type="datetime-local" id="dt" name="dt" value="2017-11-15T11:34" />`
but after submitting the form and reading the date value with
`dataForm.bindFromRequest().get.dt`
I get 1 hour more than the one that is set on the input field. Any ideas why that happens?

Comment: 1. I've updated the date pattern to use 24 hours (`HH`) instead of AM/PM hours (`hh`). 2. You could try passing a `TimeZone` as a second input to `Formats.dateFormat` and see if that helps. You may want to log the raw request value that you receive to see what the browser's sending.